# Map property type only if type is union type

Tags: typescript

I would like to map the keys of an object type to an object where:

- Each key is a key from the original type
- Each value is { enum: Array } if the type of the value is a union type
- Each value is { enum: never } if the type of the value is **not** a union type

**Example**

```
type OriginalType = {
    foo: "a" | "b";
    bar: "c";
    foobar: Record<string, string>;
};

type MappedType<T> = { ... };

type ResultType = MappedType<OriginalType>;

// ResultType = {
//    foo: { enum: ["a", "b"] }, // or foo: { enum: Array<"a" | "b"> }
//    bar: { enum: never },
//    foobar: { enum: never },
//}
```

I know how to map the keys and values to a new type, but not how to determine whether a type is a union type:

```
type IsUnion<T> = ...

type MappedType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: IsUnion<T[K]> extends true ? { enum: Array<T[K]> } : never;
};
```

Comment: check this comment https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901

Comment: You want `{enum: never}` or just `never`?  Could you fix either `ResultType` or `MappedType` so they're consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't *directly* support distinguishing unions from non-unions, so any user-defined implementation of this might have strange edge cases.  One possible approach to detecting a union type is to use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to split a type into its union members, and to compare each member with the whole unsplit type.  If the type is a union, each piece will be different from the whole.  Otherwise there will be only one piece and it will be the same as the whole.  (Well, or there will be zero pieces if the input is `never`, but hopefully that's an edge case I don't have to worry about.)  Like this:

```
type IsUnion<T, U = T> = 
  T extends unknown ? [U] extends [T] ? false : true : never;
```

Here I use a [default generic type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to copy `T` into another type parameter `U`.  We split `T` into union members (via the distributive conditional type `T extends unknown ? ⋯ : never` and we keep `U` unsplit (via the *non*-distributive conditional type `[U] extends [T] ? false : true`.  Let's test it out:

```
type U = IsUnion<number>; // false
type V = IsUnion<string | number>; // true
```

Looks reasonable.  And for your example:

```
type MappedType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: IsUnion<T[K]> extends true ? { enum: Array<T[K]> } : never;
};
type OriginalType = {
  foo: "a" | "b";
  bar: "c";
  foobar: Record<string, string>;
};
type ResultType = MappedType<OriginalType>;
/* type ResultType = {
    foo: {
        enum: ("a" | "b")[];
    };
    bar: never;
    foobar: never;
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIEkDOBVAdgSwPaoDwBUAaWZWAXljwD4yLZoAPUaVAE0VgFdUBrVTAd1SwA-LADayALp1GzNuLzTRAMwCGAG0RwAXLFAAnDjtipoAN2j6A3CAgxiNJGiy5UHALYAjS5SuwA9P6waprQYFBwAGqOKBjYOIgG6KgA5rAAPiYe3vq+AUEGRuH2AOoxzvFcvAKoeYHBGlq2EbAAsqqQMCx4EfjU5ADewLDiANKwybDc0OCYyhSSuk5xuHhio5LUDEys7IVwogN0bu66AIL6+qrg+OubsAC+sLqmFtbADzbN9gDy+ugpZIaHr2QbDYKYTC6ABEqmhGVg0M80JsI08qn0MIAxijwcpIejMbAAErQLGYfQsBJJVJERL-VK+D42OxwUmIDjqUAguDkdqdaDdXp-AFA9Q8pn+ABUeha7M53JaYJGI3xUNgQxVWuOHl0AApYfDMkjoQBKMSSVEqz7gtEYl7mSxW1UE+0mR3vJ5S-xAA)